# Having issues uploading to server using ftp_put

Tags: php, ftp

Heres my code:

```
                $host = 'ftp.uscdls.com'; 
                $usr = 'something'; 
                $pwd = 'something';         
                $local_file = 'img.png'; 
                $ftp_path = '/www.something.com'; 
                $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");      
                ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
                ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login"); 
                // perform file upload 
                ftp_chdir($conn_id, 'load_uploads'); 
                $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII); 
                if($upload) { $ftpsucc=1; } else { $ftpsucc=0; } 
                // check upload status: 
                print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete'; 
                print "\n"; 
                // close the FTP stream 
                ftp_close($conn_id);
```

It's failing on the line where it ouputs "Cannot Upload".  Ive rewritten this a couple times and i keep getting the same error.   Hoping someone has a better set of eyes on this.  Again so appreciated for any help!!  thanks!

Comment: If the file you want to upload is not located in the same directory as the script, try including the absolute path to the file. For example, 'img.png' might become '/home/user1/img.png' on a UNIX system. Providing the server log would be helpful if you have access to that and the problem remains.

Comment: Yeah figured this out after all.  turns out i needed to specify exactly the full path name including the temp file name.  thanks!